# What is the most efficient way to compute "colocation" in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis

Assuming that you have a table of the form:

```
 vehicle_id | timestamp | lat | lon
```

What is the most efficient way to create a query to compute "colocation"?
Colocation means two vehicles at nearly the same location at the same time.

What I am doing is to first create cell_id from a grid (for example created by rounding lat/lon to the 4th decimal digit) and then running a groupby on the cell_id (and time). Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a GeoHash. Demonstrating this on NYC taxicab data and grouping by hour in time:

```
WITH top_pickup_locations AS (
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(pickup_datetime, HOUR) AS hour,
  ST_GeoHash( ST_GeogPoint(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude), 15 ) AS geohash,
  COUNT(*) AS num_pickups
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_green_trips_2013`
GROUP BY hour, geohash
ORDER BY num_pickups DESC
LIMIT 10
)
SELECT
  hour,
  ST_GeogPointFromGeoHash(geohash),
  num_pickups
FROM top_pickup_locations
```

To read more about GeoHash, see here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash
Increase the number of characters (I'm using 15) to control the precision.

The other alternative is to use ST_SnapToGrid() instead of the geohash:

```
WITH top_pickup_locations AS (
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(pickup_datetime, HOUR) AS hour,
  ST_ASGeoJson(ST_SnapToGrid( ST_GeogPoint(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude), 0.0001)) AS cellid,
  COUNT(*) AS num_pickups
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.tlc_green_trips_2013`
GROUP BY hour, cellid
ORDER BY num_pickups DESC
LIMIT 10
)
SELECT
  hour,
  ST_GeogFromGeoJson(cellid),
  num_pickups
FROM top_pickup_locations
```

When I did it, the geohash method took 11 seconds of slot time
while the snap-to-grid method took 57 seconds of slot time.
15 characters of geohash and 4 digits of lat-lon are approximately similar in the number of groups.

Comment: Is there a problem when two vehicles are next to each other, but on different sides of the cell border?

Comment: yes, but if we did that, we'd end up with a N^2 algorithm, since we have to check each vehicle location against every other vehicle location.  The OP was happy with rounding off lat/lon, so this is no different.

Comment: The OP ?;-) Useful to optimize supply chain or delivery.

Comment: Does not have to be N^2. You just add 4 neighbor cells (left, top-left, top, and top-right) to each JOIN child or all 8 neighbor cells to smaller child, add extra time slot `(TIMESTAMP_SUB(datetime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`. This gives you 10x data on each side, which is reasonable espeically since you can go with smaller cells. Do intersection and remove duplicates. This handles correctly space or time-wise close events that fall into different cells.

Comment: interesting ... michael, can you add full answer?